# How to use "cry after" in passive form?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, passive-voice

I intend to say "They would cry after me (my death).".

Here is the sentence:

> "I didn't know how to live my life, yet I would be cried after so damn good."

Is this correct? If not, could you please give me a hand on this?

Comment: If it's not correct, how would you say it right?

Comment: Is that correct? No, not really, but you're speaking informally and colloquially, so I don't think that matters. If you weren't speaking informally and colloquially, you wouldn't be able to use "good" as an adverb or drop the word "damn," either. That said, unless there were some further context to indicate that by "after" you mean "after I died," I would sooner think that "cry after" would mean "call after," like when one yells out to someone who's walking away or leaving.

Comment: "Cry after" seems to be an old English usage that does not mean what you think; for instance here is what you can find: " For to cry after one is an evidence of settled hatred" (https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Commentaries/L75FAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22cried+after%22&pg=PA134&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Try thinking about it this way.  It is obvious what you mean.  And the passive form is properly formed.

Comment: I edited the question and provided a background on the nature of the passage.

Comment: What are you trying to express by the phrase “cry after”? The natural reading is that someone is trying to catch your attention, possibly by hurling insults.

Comment: Active: *They would mourn me.* Passive: *I would be mourned.*

Comment: ♫ "Don't cry after me, Argentina... The truth is, I'd never be cried after..." ♫

Comment: “I would be **sorely missed after** my death”. OR “yet they would (damn well) **cry at my funeral**“

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking about it this way.

It is obvious what you mean.  And the passive form is properly formed.  I could suggest that the problem is that the 'cry' that is used in 'cry after' is intransitive, and that is why "I would be cried after" sounds odd.

But there are parallel formations that are apparently similar but also correct. 'Look' in 'look after' is intransitive, but we certainly talk about people and cars being 'well looked after' (or 'cared for').

I have checked the Cambridge online dictionary and the Merriam Webster Online dictionar, and neither includes 'cry after' and I myself do not recognise it.  If you use it, therefore you are using an expression not widely used, if at all.  So it will sound odd to people reading it.  If you are a brilliant writer and include it in a poem or story or pop song that catches on, perhaps it will catch on.  But till that happens, it will sound odd.

Comment: Great answer. This passage is from a book I had written long time ago but recently got the chance to translate: (...I didn’t know how to properly use a computer, yet I would be used so damn good by people, maybe I should have added this on my CV, under the section of computer skills. I again started talking nonsense, I didn’t know how to say goodbye, yet I was so good at hugging. For instance, I didn’t know how to live my life, yet I would be cried after so damn good...) How would you correct "cry after" part?

Comment: Start by looking at a good thesaurus.  Look up some word like 'lament', 'mourn' ... and see whether you find something you think works.  Before you use it, check that it has a passive use.

Comment: "I didn’t know how to live my life, yet I would be mourned so damn good." Is this correct and easily understandable?

Comment: @noone235711 the choice of expression is yours.  You might find an expression that you feel fits better.  We are not editors.  You are the writer.